# What am I doing wrong in reversing part of this linked list?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

I'm trying to reverse part a linked list using the following method.

```
public void reversePart(int start, int end){

    if(start > end || end >size || start <0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid indices provided!");

    int count = end-start;
    LinkedListNode<Integer> tmp = head;
    LinkedListNode<Integer> reversalEnd = head;

    //skip start nodes;
    while(start>0){
        tmp=tmp.next;
        start--;
    }
//point where we need to reconnect the list.
    while(end>0){
        end--;
        reversalEnd=reversalEnd.next;//prepare reversal end node to connect to reversalEnd .
    }
    reversalEnd= reversalEnd.next;
    LinkedListNode<Integer> startRev= tmp;

    LinkedListNode<Integer> prev= null;
    LinkedListNode<Integer> nxt= null;
    //reverseSubList
    while(count>0){
        count--;
        nxt= startRev.next;
        startRev.next=prev;
        prev = startRev;
        if(count ==0)
            break;
        startRev=nxt;
    }
    tmp.next=startRev;// debugger crashes here. 
    nxt.next=reversalEnd;   
}
```

When I run the program it runs indefinitely, upon trying to debug, I notice that it runs as expected up till the point the reversal is complete and the debugger seems to crash at the marked line.

Any thoughts on what Im doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, the reversal works, but it's the final re-attachment that fails.

Assume the following list: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`. By the time you reach `tmp.next=startRev;`, the variables look like this:

```
tmp = 5,null;
reversalEnd = 9,10,null;
startRev = 7,6,5,null;
prev = 7,6,5,null;
nxt = 8,9,10,null;
```

The `null` represents that there is no `next`.

The **important** point to note here is that the `node` which holds the value `5` is referenced by several variables, notably `tmp` & in the third element of `startRev`. I.e. both point to the **exact same node**.

So, when doing `tmp.next=startRev;`, `5` will now point to `7` next. `7` points to `6`, and `6` points to `5`, which is the same `5` from the beginning. So, you got yourself a circular loop there.

```
5,7,6,5,7,6,5,7,6,5,7,6,5,7,6,5,7,6,5,7,6,5,7,6,5,7,6,5,7,6,5,7,6,5...
```

Hence why the debugger crashed. You simply need to re-attach `startRev` at the node `4` instead of `5`. So, along with `tmp`, have a `prevTmp` also.

Also note that remaining elements (`8,9,10`) are lost or disconnected from the main list. So, to reconnect them, you need a reference of node `5` & attach it to its `next`. `tmp` would come in handy here.

Hope I could properly explain where you're going wrong.

Comment: why is temp `5,null` and not `5,6,7,8,9,10,null`?

Comment: `5` is the first element to go through the while loop. `startRev.next=prev;` makes `5.next`=`null`, since `prev` is `null` initially. And again, startRev's value is reflected in `tmp`, so `tmp = 5,null;`.